# How to skip over errors created by cursors running through empty tables?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, cursor

I am trying to automate the creation of many different feature layers were their content is created by a cursor. Sometimes during the automation, a feature layer may be empty, this is okay, but as the cursor runs through the layer adding in the data, the `del row` line returns the error:

`"NameError: name 'row' is not defined"` and stops the script.

Question:
If a layer I am creating happens to be empty, how can I skip over any errors that might pop up due to the cursor not being able to define itself in an empty table?

Already Tried:
I tried setting a 'count' variable to how many rows are in each table, and telling python to skip over the table if it has less than 1 row, but the "del row" line still caused a fuss, and I had trouble setting up the try statement.

The code below is still returning the error. It is not printing empty cursor yet the `ACount` is indeed 0.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("A_Squares", ["LEGEND"])
ACount = arcpy.GetCount_management("A_Squares")
print ACount
if ACount == 0:
    print "empty cursor"
else:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = TableA
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    del row
    del cursor
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using the _GetCount_ tool to get the number of rows and using that to skip tables that sounds a very sensible way of doing it. So if that is your control over if a loop executes then it sounds like you are destroying rows when none were ever created? Without seeing the code I would suggest you review the logic of your code and look at when you create and destroy row objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from the GetCount method is not fully correct, so your if statement is not going down the correct path.  Use the .GetOutput method:

```
count = arcpy.GetCount_management("A_Squares")
ACount = int(count.getOutput(0))

if ACount == 0:
    print "empty cursor"
else:
    for row in cursor:
        #...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be completely necessary to delete the row object, but if you just define it first you should be golden.

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("whatever")
row = None # Define it here

for row in iter(cursor.next, None):
    # ...

del cursor
del row
```